# React приложение. Cross origin запрос

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Решил попробовать Реакт.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React</title>
    <script src="js/react.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/babel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
```

И собственно скрипт

```
'use strict';

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hi</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Выдается ошибка

```
babel.js:12 Failed to load file:///.../js/app.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Что я сделал не так?

p.s. Если я просто напишу код в теге скрипт, вместо подключения файла, то всё заработает

Comment: Вы забыли использовать веб-сервер...

Comment: parcel в помощь или вебпак

Comment: или create-react-app